# Performing specific operation on first element of list using Java8 streaming

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to perform certain operation on first element of my list and different operation for all remaining elements.

Here is my code snippet:

```
List<String> tokens = getDummyList();
if (!tokens.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("this is first token:" + tokens.get(0));
}
tokens.stream().skip(1).forEach(token -> {
    System.out.println(token);
});
```

Is there any more cleaner way to achieve this preferably using java 8 streaming API.

Comment: I think that your approach is already clean and concise :)

Comment: One thing I would do to prevent NPE is also check for `tokens` being `null`

Comment: yes that is just dummy code to explain the question. I was wondering whether there is some way to merge that if condition within streaming call and reduce few more number of lines.

Comment: @vatsalmevada No.

Answer (score 11):

One way to express the intention is

```
Spliterator<String> sp = getDummyList().spliterator();
if(sp.tryAdvance(token -> System.out.println("this is first token: "+token))) {
    StreamSupport.stream(sp, false).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

which works with arbitrary `Collection`s, not only `List`s and is potentially more efficient than `skip` based solutions when more advanced `Stream` operations are chained. This pattern is also applicable to a `Stream` source, i.e. when multiple traversal is not possible or could yield two different results.

```
Spliterator<String> sp=getDummyList().stream().filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).spliterator();
if(sp.tryAdvance(token -> System.out.println("this is first non-empty token: "+token))) {
    StreamSupport.stream(sp, false).map(String::toUpperCase).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

However, the special treatment of the first element might still cause a performance loss, compared to processing all stream elements equally.

If all you want to do is applying an action like `forEach`, you can also use an `Iterator`:

```
Iterator<String> tokens = getDummyList().iterator();
if(tokens.hasNext())
    System.out.println("this is first token:" + tokens.next());
tokens.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

Comment: the iterator should be the accepted solution IMHO. +1

Answer (score 8):

would this be cleaner

```
    items.stream().limit(1).forEach(v -> System.out.println("first: "+ v));
    items.stream().skip(1).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: that or findFirst()

Comment: Attempting to operate on the *same* stream throws `IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed`