# How do I get the first element while continue streaming?

Tags: java, for-loop, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a stream of generic items. I'd like to print the class name of the first item + the `toString()` of all the items.

If I had an Iterable, it would look like this:

```
Iterable<E> itemIter = ...;
boolean first = true;
for (E e : itemIter) {
    if (first) {
        first = false;
        System.out.println(e.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Can I do this on a stream (`Stream<T>`) with the stream API?

* Please note that it's a question about streams - not about iterators. I have a stream - not an iterator.

Comment: Please note that it's a question about streams - not about iterators. I have a stream - not an iterator.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko - I don't have an `Iterable` - just `Stream`.

Comment: Note that, if you have a stream, you can [get an iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#iterator--) (and, if you need one, [also an iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702989/how-to-iterate-with-foreach-loop-over-java-8-stream/31703176#31703176)).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, if I convert the stream to an iterator, I might loose the concurrency capability.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is [`StreamEx`](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library that extends standard Java's Stream API. Using [`StreamEx.of(Iterator)`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#of-java.util.Iterator-) and [`peekFirst`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#peekFirst-java.util.function.Consumer-) :

```
StreamEx.of(itemIter.iterator())
        .peekFirst(e -> System.out.println(e.getClass().getSimpleName()))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I wonder how they've implemented it, probably like one of the solutions already given here

Comment: note that the method has some limitations (mentioned in the docs) and "exists mainly to support debugging".

Comment: @Lino combine [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40636566/2711488)  which performs an action for the first element (but also consumes it) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46077388/2711488) which will push the first item back after examining it and you have the necessary tools to construct such an operation.

Comment: By the way, it’s preferable to use `StreamEx.of(itemIter.spliterator())`, which may carry additional meta information to the stream (depending on the actual `Iterable`), potentially improving the performance.

Answer (score 10):

**Native solution:** `Stream` in Java is not reusable. This means, that consuming stream can be done only once. If you get the first element from a stream, you can iterate over it one more time.

Workaround would be to create another stream same as the first one or getting the first item and then creating a stream, something like that:

```
Stream<E> stream = StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(sourceIterator, Spliterator.ORDERED), false);
E firstElement = itemIter.next();
stream.foreach(...);
```

**Edit**

There is not really any way to "copy" a stream, you need to keep an iterator / collection. More about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474838/can-i-duplicate-a-stream-in-java-8). When it comes to memory once stream is exhausted, it can be collected by garbage collector as there is no use from it. Stream itself does not take more space than iterator it originates from. Bear in mind, that streams can be potentially infinite. Elements currently manipulated are stored in memory.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka please don't ask about the memory implications :) To me, it's obvious that none of Stream API solutions will outdo the simple loop approach mentioned by you (I'd go with a fori loop, though) in any way (performance, readability, maintenance). I honestly don't understand why you want streams here.

Comment: Why do you assume that it's safe to cast: `(List<E>) itemIter`?

Comment: @ernest_k it doesn't really matter, I don't know the context (what `itemIter` really is). Let's just treat it as a pseudocode, that can be compiled, just to show the idea :)

Comment: Well, it doesn’t even compile. Since objects are not an `Iterable` and an `Iterator` at the same time, you can’t cast it to `List` and expect it to also have a `next()` method. Once you fixed this, you don’t need the questionable type cast: `E firstElement = itemIter.iterator().next(); Stream<E> stream = StreamSupport.stream(itemIter.spliterator(), false);`

Answer (score 10):

If your starting point is a `Stream` and you want to retain all of its properties and the laziness, the following solution will do:

```
public static <E> Stream<E> forFirst(Stream<E> stream, Consumer<? super E> c) {
    boolean parallel = stream.isParallel();
    Spliterator<E> sp = stream.spliterator();
    return StreamSupport.stream(() -> {
        if(sp.getExactSizeIfKnown() == 0) return sp;
        Stream.Builder<E> b = Stream.builder();
        if(!sp.tryAdvance(b.andThen(c))) return sp;
        return Stream.concat(b.build(), StreamSupport.stream(sp, parallel)).spliterator();
    }, sp.characteristics(), parallel);
}
```

E.g. when you use it with

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of("foo", "bar", "baz"));
Stream<String> stream = forFirst(
        list.stream().filter(s -> s.startsWith("b")),
        s -> System.out.println(s+" ("+s.getClass().getSimpleName()+')')
    ).map(String::toUpperCase);
list.add(1, "blah");
System.out.println(stream.collect(Collectors.joining(" | ")));
```

it will print

```
blah (String)
BLAH | BAR | BAZ
```

demonstrating that the processing will not start before commencing the terminal operation (`collect`), hence reflecting the preceding update to the source `List`.

Comment: can't tell why this is not a lot higher :|

Comment: @Eugene because posted two hours after the other answers and being placed at the end in the default ordering… nothing to worry about

Answer (score 6):

You can abuse reduction:

```
Stream<E> stream = ...;
System.out.println(stream
                   .reduce("",(out,e) -> 
                   out + (out.isEmpty() ? e.getClass().getSimpleName()+"\n" : "")
                   + e));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `peek` for that:

```
AtomicBoolean first = new AtomicBoolean(true);
StreamSupport.stream(itemIter.spliterator(), false)
    .peek(e -> {
        if(first.get()) {
            System.out.println(e.getClass().getSimpleName());
            first.set(false);
        }
    })
    ...
```

Comment: In that sense, I guess the code in question would be much better even if the iterable is defined. Keeping in mind there is nothing like `itemIter.stream()` available up front.

Comment: @nullpointer you're right, I've edited my answer to use StreamSupport

Comment: The action passed to `peek` will be executed in the processing order which is not guaranteed to be the Stream’s encounter order.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to do it like this -

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
public class MyClass {
   static int i = 0;
   static int getCounter(){
       return i;
   }
   static void incrementCounter(){
       i++;
   }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"); 
        List<String> answer = list.stream().filter(str -> {if(getCounter()==0) {System.out.println("First Element : " + str);} incrementCounter(); return true;}). 
        collect(Collectors.toList()); 
        System.out.println(answer); 
    }
}
```

Output :

```
First Element : A
[A, B, C, D, E, F, G]
```

Comment: requires you to always reset the value though, and will not work in a multi thread environment

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an boolean atomic reference:

```
AtomicReference<Boolean> first = new AtomicReference<Boolean>(Boolean.TRUE);
stream.forEach(e -> 
         System.out.println("First == " + first.getAndUpdate(b -> false)));
```